# Software systems to prevent storages to wear out

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, storage, data-loss-prevention

There are huge amount (thousand of thousands) of storages in big data centers. So eveday some number of them are wear out and even sometimes burn out. Are there any software or intellectual systems (neural networks?) that can help to predict and prevent such situations to replace "future-failed" storages in advance?

Answer (score 1):

If you're refering to Linux, then smartctl. However SSD disks may be connected with HW RAID controllers, then you have to use utilities which can work with such a controller (usually provided by the HW vendor).

It's also common to use spare disks, so in case some disk goes down, it's replaced with one of spare disks.

The SNMP alarm generation is usually also possible.